# Probability of next head given sequence of heads and prior on heads distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Quant interview:

A machine produces a weighted coin that lands on heads with an
unknown probability $p$, and we know that $P(p \leq x)=x^{4}$.
You flip the coin $5$ times, and every time it lands on heads.
What is the probability that the next flip will also land on heads?

**Attempt**:
Using bayes $P(NextHead|5Heads)=\frac{P(6Heads)}{P(Head)}=p^5$ then I took the expectation given the prior distribution and obtain as answer $E(p^5)=1/10$.

Comment: Why is the denominator $P(Head)$?

Comment: $\frac1{10}$ looks very low: both the prior and the observations seems to suggest the coin is likely to be biased towards heads, not against.

Comment: In any case, the probability that the next flip will also land on heads is $p$ (for which you should be able to find a posterior distribution)

Comment: @Henry would you agree with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Following @angryavian comment, the correct denominator should be $P(5Heads)$ therefore the probability of the next head given 5 heads is $p$.

Following @Henry comment, the posterior distribution for p is equal to $9p^8$, the mean of this distribution is 9/10 which I suppose is equal to the probability I am searching for.

**Follow up:** why is the probability given by the mean of the posterior and not let's say the mode?

Comment: One reason for using $\mathbb E[p \mid 5\text{ Heads}]$ is that if you drew a large number of values of $p$ from your posterior distribution and then flipped coins based on those $p$s, then the proportion of Heads you would see would be about $\frac{9}{10}$.

Comment: To make this answer more helpful for the community, it would be worth explaining how you (1) computed the posterior and (2) how you used the provided cumulative distribution function $P(p \leq x) = x^4$ to get to your final answer of $\frac{9}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

The prior $\mathsf P(p\le x)=x^4$ is the posterior you’d get if you started with a uniform prior $\mathsf P(p\le x)=x$ and then observed $3$ heads. If you then observe $5$ heads, the situation is the same as if you’d started with a uniform prior and observed $3+5=8$ heads. By the [rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession), the probability that the coin will show heads on the next toss is then $\frac{8+1}{8+2}=\frac9{10}$.